# Matlab Deleting data if percentage NaN is too high

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nan, percentage

I have a data set which consists of 24 batches of data in time order in consecutive rows. Which I have this code for to show where the indices are:

```
%Re calculate the batch indices due to deletion
indbatch =1;
for it=2:size(Data,1)
    if Data(it,2)<Data(it-1,2)
        indbatch=[indbatch,it];
    end
end
indbatch=[indbatch,it+1]; %gives the ind of start of each batch
```

I am trying to see if the percentage of missing data (NaN) values in each batch is too high in order to delete the batch. To simplify the first batches are from rows 1:250 then second batch row 251:510. So I want to know how to code the loop to calculate the percentage of NaN in each batch if percentage is greater than 80% record batch number in order yo delete
This is what I have so far but this doesn't work due to the Ind bit I think and also the percentage bit only uses length and should use row*length ...

```
for ib=1:length(indbatch)-1       %each batch (24 batches)
tspan=[indbatch(ib):indbatch(ib+1)-1]; % gives the time span of each batch

for iv = 1:49
    Ind = find(isnan(Data(tspan,iv)));
    Check = isempty(Ind);
    if Check == 1 
        continue
    else
        Percentage_Missing = (length(Ind)/ length(Data)) * 100;
        if Percentage_Missing >= 80
            Delete = [Delete, iv];
        else
            continue
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you give us a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), especially for some test data to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove rows from `Data` where more than 80% of the values are NaN, you can do this with some logical matrix manipulation.

```
%// Find all NaN values
isMissing = isnan(Data(tSpan, :));

%// Compute the number of NaNs for each column of Data
nMissing = sum(isMissing, 1);

%// Compute this as a percentage
percentMissing = nMissing ./ size(isMissing, 1);

%// Now figure out which columns to remove
toRemove = percentMissing >= 0.80;

%// And use this to index into the data
notMissingData = Data(tSpan, ~toRemove);
```